# Why am I receiving extra characters on serial terminal emulator? & avoiding them?

Tags: c, stm32, serial-communication, keil, usart

I am currently trying to implement serial communication on STM32F103C8T6 micro controller with interrupts. The code written by me "semi" works as I try to send characters ABCDE individually but my Terminal application on desktop(Putty) is showing my some missed characters.

My result in terminal emulator
Why are few characters repeating? & how to avoid this?

```
ABBCDEABCDEEABCDEABCCDEABCDEABBCDEABCDEEABCDEABCCDEABCDEAABCDEABCDDEABCDEABCCDEA
BCDEAABCDEABCDDEABCDEABBCDEABCDEEABCDEABCDDEABCDEABBCDEABCDEEABCDEABCCDEABCDEAAB
CDEABCDEEABCDEABCCDEABCDEAABCDEABCDDEABCDEABBCDEABCDEAABCDEABCDDEABCDEABBCDEABCD
```

Please fond my Code below

usart.c

```
#include "usart.h"

void usart_init(uint32_t BaudRate)
{
    SystemCoreClockUpdate();
    RCC->APB2ENR |=(RCC_APB2ENR_IOPAEN | RCC_APB2ENR_AFIOEN | RCC_APB2ENR_USART1EN);
    GPIOA->CRH |= (GPIO_CRH_MODE9_0 | GPIO_CRH_MODE9_1);
    GPIOA->CRH &= ~(GPIO_CRH_MODE10_0 | GPIO_CRH_MODE10_1);
    GPIOA->CRH |= GPIO_CRH_CNF9_1;
    GPIOA->CRH &= ~GPIO_CRH_CNF9_0;
    GPIOA->CRH |= GPIO_CRH_CNF10_0;
    GPIOA->CRH &= ~GPIO_CRH_CNF10_1;
    
    USART1->BRR = (SystemCoreClock/BaudRate);
    USART1->CR1 |= (USART_CR1_UE | USART_CR1_RE | USART_CR1_TE);
    //USART1->CR1 |= USART_CR1_TXEIE;
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART1_IRQn);
}

void buffer_init(void)
{
    TxBuffer.in = 0;
    TxBuffer.out = 0;
}

void putchar(unsigned char data)
{
    __disable_irq();
    struct Buffer_Struct *p = &TxBuffer;
    p->Buffer[p->in & (BufferSize - 1)] = data;
    p->in++;    
    if(tx_start)
    {
        tx_start = 0;
        USART1->CR1 |=USART_CR1_TXEIE;
    }
    __enable_irq();
}

void USART1_IRQHandler(void)
{
    struct Buffer_Struct *p;
    if(USART1->SR & USART_SR_TXE)
    {
        p = &TxBuffer;
        if(p->in != p->out)
        {
            USART1->DR = (p->Buffer[p->out & (BufferSize - 1)] & 0x1FF);
            p->out++;
            tx_start = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

usart.h

```
#ifndef USART_H
#define USART_H
#include "stm32f10x.h"
#include <stdbool.h>

#define BufferSize      64

struct Buffer_Struct {
    unsigned int in;
    unsigned int out;
    unsigned char Buffer[BufferSize];
};

static struct Buffer_Struct TxBuffer = {0,0, };

static bool tx_start = 1;

void buffer_init(void);
void usart_init(uint32_t BaudRate);
void putchar(unsigned char data);

#endif
```

main.c

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"
#include "usart.h"

int main (void)
{
    usart_init(9600);
    while(1)
    {
        putchar('A');
        putchar('B');
        putchar('C');
        putchar('D');
        putchar('E');
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably need to connect a debugger to your board, and add a few breakpoints or step through the code.

Comment: Where should i be adding the breakpoints i already tried with one at IRQhandler and at putchar()

Comment: Well those would be my suggestions. Not knowing much about STM32, can interrupts be nested? For example, could there be a second serial port interrupt while the first is still being processed?

Comment: i am not nesting interrupts, I even disabled the interrupts while writing to a buffer.

Comment: I'm more worried about if `USART1_IRQHandler` could be called twice.

Comment: Also, are you *sure* it's a problem in the sending side (your program), and not in the receiving terminal program? Have you connected a serial monitor to see what's really sent over the serial line?

Comment: Your main loop adds characters to the buffer at a rate much much higher than the UART can keep up with. What you are seeing is the effect of the characters in the buffer being constantly overwritten with new characters. `putchar` clearly misses a mechanism to wait until there is space in the buffer.

Comment: shoul i try a higher baud rate?

Comment: @varun_koganti Are you getting this duplications from the very first byte sent, or only once you have called `putchar` at least 64 times (and the indexing starts to wrap)? What happens if you change the condition in the interrupt function from `p->in != p->out` to `p->out < p->in`? What happens if you add a condition in `putchar` to make sure that `p->in` never wraps `p->out`?

Comment: sometimes from the first transmit, but as i slowly step through the code the errors are not coming anymore.

Comment: Make all variables shared with the ISR `volatile` to prevent potential optimization bugs. That is `TxBuffer ` and `tx_start`.

Comment: I'm not quite following what the in and out variables are doing or how they are supposed to work.

Comment: Increasing the baud rate will not be sufficient. Your microcontroller will always be considerably faster than the UART and overrun the buffer. Either you need to wait in `putchar` until data has been sent and space is available for new data, or you can add a delay in the loop in `main()`. At 9600 bps, you can send at most 960 characters per second, i.e. 5 characters every 5ms. To be on the safe side, insert a delay of 10ms at the end of the loop.

Comment: @varun_koganti you need to disable txe interrupt when there is no data to send

Answer (score 1):

Your interrupt handler is incorrect. It will be invoked all the time as TXE is always empty if you do not put anything there. You need to disable the interrupt in the interrupt handler.

I also like to use compiler to do the job and try to use bitfields if buffer size is a power of 2

```
#define BufferSize         6      

struct Buffer_Struct {
    volatile unsigned int in : BufferSize;
    volatile unsigned int out : BufferSize;
    unsigned char Buffer[2 << BufferSize];
};


void putchar(unsigned char data)
{
    TxBuffer.Buffer[TxBuffer.in] = data;
    TxBuffer.in++;    
    USART1->CR1 |=USART_CR1_TXEIE;
}

void USART1_IRQHandler(void)
{
    if(USART1->SR & USART_SR_TXE)
    {
        if(TxBuffer.in != TxBuffer.out)
        {
            USART1->DR = TxBuffer.Buffer[TxBuffer.out];
            TxBuffer.out++;
            if(TxBuffer.out == TxBuffer.in)
                USART1->CR1 &= ~USART_CR1_TXEIE;
        }
    }
}
```

Your putchar function is wrong as well because it does not check if the buffer is full.

BTW you do not have to disable IRQs in this case as you do not modify the same variables.

Comment: the reason for disabling IRQ is this is being operated in RTOS environement, yes SysTick has highest priority followed by pendSV(Systick prempting PenSV), I donot want something happening while i am trying to receive some very important data over USART such as telemetry info for drone.

Comment: then use RTOS critical section functions. BTW code does not look RTOS